# Reading Data from Hive through Pyspark

Tags: python, hive, pyspark

I am trying to read data from Hive table through Pyspark. I have successfully built connection between Hive and spark. I am also able to see tables present within databases but when I try to query the table I am getting this error:

**CODE:**
`spark.sql("select count(*) from my_table").show(truncate = False)`

Error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.showString

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution using `SQLContext()`:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sqlC = SQLContext(sc)

sqlC.sql("select count(*) from my_table").show(truncate = False)
```

or try this using `HiveContext()`:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sc = SparkContext()
hivctx = HiveContext(sc)

hivctx.sql("select count(*) from my_table").show(truncate = False)
```

Comment: Is your table saved in a database? can you tell me the type of `my_table`?

Comment: Yes table is in Hive database. my_table is the table name inside hive database

Comment: if i execute my query like this: df= sparkSession.sql('select * from my_table') .. it doesn't give an error.. i can even view table schema by executing df which shows DataFrame[_version_: bigint, app: string, bytes: smallint, city: string, client_ip: string, code: tinyint, country_code: string, country_code3: string].. but i can't able to access the data of that table

Comment: Is there any non `UTF-8` or `null` characters in your table?

Comment: I've looked at similar error solutions and they said that maybe this is the reason. try `df.registerTempTable('testTable')` and then `spark.sql('select count(*) from testTable').show()`. **Do Not read from hive database**. check if you get the same error or not!